# Does the thundering herd issue still exist in epoll of new Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, concurrency

I saw that `fs/eventpoll.c` in the kernel source code is written like this:

```
static int ep_poll(struct eventpoll *ep, struct epoll_event __user *events,
           int maxevents, long timeout)
{
....
        init_waitqueue_entry(&wait, current);
        __add_wait_queue_exclusive(&ep->wq, &wait);    // *** NB
....
}
```

Does that "exclusive" mean that only one wait item (process or thread in userspace) will be waked up?

But when I wrote some test code, I saw that the [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) still exists.

And WHY can't it be solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In the kernel code we can see in `include/linux/wait.h` that `__add_wait_queue_exclusive()` adds the entry to the head of the list:

```
 __add_wait_queue_exclusive(wait_queue_head_t *q, wait_queue_t *wait)
{
        wait->flags |= WQ_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE;
        __add_wait_queue(q, wait);
}
```

When it comes to waking up static void `__wake_up_common()` in `sched/wait.c` does wake only the first tasks that are not exclusive and the first exclusive one.
So normally only one tasks gets woken up.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you are using the same epfd. The flag WQ_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE is works only for the TASKs waiting on the same eventpoll.

If your testing code use different epfd monitor on the same socket, YES, the issue exists.